# Significance of `1 in Stack Trace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

What is the significance of `1 in a Stack Trace?

```
   at Default.Process() in Default.cs:line 19
   at Framework.BasePage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in BasePage.cs:line 82
   at Framework.Endpoint`1.Page[T](HttpContext context) in Endpoint.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Third line: **Endpoint`1**

Comment: It means it's a generic class that takes a single type argument

Comment: So there's a circumstance that it could be `2?

Comment: Yes, that would be a generic class that takes two type arguments

Comment: Such as Dictionary<>?

Comment: @jscarle Yes, in Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, you get System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2. And there will be cases where you get more than two, as in System.Action

Comment: Awesome. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) (or count) of the generic arguments.

The reason for it is that you can have multiple classes with the same name, but with a different number of generic parameters. For example:

```
class Foo {}
class Foo<TKey> {}
class Foo<TKey, TValue> {}
```

In order to differentiate them the common language runtime specifies the rule that the generic types have suffixed with the number of generic arguments that take. Non generic types don't require this, so their names get encoded as:

```
Foo
Foo`1
Foo`2
```

There are some other "magic" characters that are used. For example `+` in a name is used to indicate an inner/nested class. So:

```
class Foo
{
  class Bar
  {
  }
}
```

Would result in `Bar` being encoded as `Foo+Bar`.